# How to query a field in MongoDB with a boolean value and return a boolean whether it's true or false

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, boolean-logic

**Check my simple collection:**

```
{_id: "01",
  name: "Jimmy",
  canDrive: false }
```

What I want to do once a `document` is found, is to manipulate a DOM and show a `<div class="driving-tutorial>` if the field `canDrive` value is `false` and hide it if the value is `true`

**Like this in meteor:**

```
Template.profile.rendered = function() {
    if (<query>,<field> == true){
        $('.driving-tutorial').hide();
    else {
        $('.driving-tutorial').show(); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement this logic with the [**`findOne()`**](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-findOne) method which finds the first document that matches the selector/query object in the arguments. Thus you can call [**`findOne()`**](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-findOne) with a Mongo selector, which is an object that specifies a required set of attributes of the desired document to match a document. For example, this selector

```
var doc = Model.findOne({ canDrive: false });
```

will match this document

```
{
    _id: "01",
    name: "Jimmy",
    canDrive: false 
}
```

You can then use the above logic in your template function to check for the existence of a document and the field, also bearing in mind that [**`findOne()`**](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-findOne) will return null if it fails to find a matching document, which often happens if the document hasn't been loaded yet or has been removed from the collection:

```
Template.profile.rendered = function() {
    var doc = Model.findOne({ canDrive: false });
    if (doc && !doc.canDrive){
        $('.driving-tutorial').show();
    else {
        $('.driving-tutorial').hide(); 
    }
}
```

You can also use the jquery [**`toggle()`**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method's second version which accepts a Boolean parameter. If this parameter is `true`, then the matched elements are shown; if `false`, the elements are hidden:

```
Template.profile.rendered = function() {
    var doc = Model.findOne({ canDrive: false }),
        canDrive = (doc && !doc.canDrive);
    $('.driving-tutorial').toggle(canDrive);
}
```

Comment: *face palm* -- it's dot notation. also appreciate the `toggle()` advise